# Power and factorial series sum Explanation

Tags: java, math, recursion, series

**Question:**

*A class SeriesSum is designed to calculate the sum of the following series:*

[image: question]

Class name : SeriesSum

Data members/instance variables:

x : to store an integer number

n : to store number of terms

sum : double variable to store the sum of the series

Member functions:

SeriesSum(int xx, int nn) : constructor to assign x=xx and n=nn

double findfact(int m) to return the factorial of m using recursive
technique.

double findpower(int x, int y) : to return x raised to the power of y using
recursive technique.

void calculate( ) : to calculate the sum of the series by invoking
the recursive functions respectively

void display( ) : to display the sum of the series

(a) Specify the class SeriesSum, giving details of the constructor(int, int),
double findfact(int), double findpower(int, int), void calculate( ) and
void display( ).

Define the main( ) function to create an object and call the
functions accordingly to enable the task.

**Code:**

```
class SeriesSum
    {
    int x,n;
    double sum;
    SeriesSum(int xx,int nn)
    { x=xx;
    n=nn;
    sum=0.0;
    }
    double findfact(int a)
    { return (a<2)? 1:a*findfact(a-1);
    }
    double findpower(int a, int b)
    { return (b==0)? 1:a*findpower(a,b-1);
    }
    void calculate()
    { for(int i=2;i<=n;i+=2)
    sum += findpower(x,i)/findfact(i-1);
    }
    void display()
    { System.out.println("sum="+ sum);
    }
    static void main()
    { SeriesSum obj = new SeriesSum(3,8);
    obj.calculate();
    obj.display();
    }
}
```

**MyProblem:**

I am having problems in understanding that when i= any odd number (Taking an example such as 3 here)then it value that passes through findfact is (i-1)=2 then how am I getting the odd factorials such as 3!

*Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.*

**Optional:**

If you can somehow explain the recursion taking place in the findpower and findfactorial,it would be of great help.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your definition of `findfact()` seems to be correct (although using a recursive definition is needlessly inefficient). If you want to find 3! with it -- give it the input 3. How is it even an issue?

Comment: 3! = 5! / 5 / 4, x^^n-2 = x^n / x / x, use this.

Comment: @JohnColeman I can include the whole question if you want.

Comment: Are you asking how recursion works? 3! = 3*2! = 3*2*1! = 3*2*1 = 6.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes exactly.You for my point.I am asking how recursion works in findfact () and findpower().By the way thanks for understanding my doubt correctly.If you can provide a more easier approach with recursion,it would be great.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have provided you the complete question for understanding my doubt more clearly.

Comment: This is not a very good way to evaluate this series.  You should never be calling a factorial function for those terms in the denominator.  You know that, right?

Comment: @duffymo yes absolutely but I need to follow this process even if I don't want.In our examination I need to go by the guidelines of the question else I will not be given marks.Bad education system which produces bad programmers, that's it.

Comment: I doubt "yes, absolutely" very much.  I'd code it the way it should be done and let the exam fall where it may.

Comment: @duffymo by the way I just wanted to ask one last thing ,are these kind of questions acceptable to the community?I mean by the context and by formatting.I will be asking more questions in future , that's why I am asking.

Comment: @duffymo if I do that I will not be given admission to any university and I will be thrown out of the house for my bad marks.I hope you don't want that for me.Thanks for your concern by the way.

Comment: Your formatting is not good.  It's unreadable.  If I can't read and understand it, perhaps you can't either.  You should not post your assignments without an attempt at code.  Read the FAQ to see how to ask good questions.

Comment: @duffymo OK I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look a the loop. `i` starts at 2 and is incremented by 2 every iteration, so it is never odd. It corresponds to the successive powers of `x`, each of which is divided by the factorial of `i -1` (which IS odd).

As for the recursion in `findfact`, you just need to unwrap the first few calls by hand to see why it works :

```
findfact(a) = a * findfact(a -1) 
    = a * (a - 1) * findfact(a -2)
    = a * (a - 1) * (a - 2) * findfact(a - 3)
    ...
    = a * (a - 1) * (a - 2) * ... * 2 * findfact(1)
    = a * (a - 1) * (a - 2) * ... * 2 * 1
    = a!*
```

The same reasoning works with `findpower`.

As a side note, while it may be helpful for teaching purposes, recursion is a terrible idea for computing factorials or powers.

Comment: Yes thanks for notifying it ,I absolutely overlooked it.My fault sorry!!

Comment: Yes you are correct recursion is really a terrible idea,it is slow and consumes more memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I try to help you the best I can.

#### I am having problems in understanding that when i= any odd number

In this code i never will be any odd number

```
for(int i=2;i<=n;i+=2)
```

i will be: 2 , 4 , 6 , 8 and so on because `i+=2`

#### The Recursion

The findfact() function in a more readable version:

```
  double findfact(int a){
    if(a < 2 ){
      return 1;
    } else {
      return a * findfact(a - 1);
    }
  }
```

you can imagine it as a staircase, every call of findfact is a step:
[image]

We test: if a < 2 then return 1 else we call `findfact()` again with `a-1` and multiply `a` with the result of `findfact()`

The same function without recursion:

```
  double findfact(int a){
    int sum = 1;
    for(int i = a; i > 0; i--){
      sum *= i;
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Same by the findpower function:
if b == 0 then return 1 else call `findpower()` with `a, b-1` and multiply the return value of `findpower()` with `a`

So the last called findpower() will return `1` (b = 0)

 
The second last findpower() will return `a * 1` (b = 1)

 
The third last findpower() will return `a * a * 1` (b = 2)

 
so you can see findpower(a, 2) = a * a * 1 = a^2

Hope I could help you

Comment: Thanks for your solution.Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the summation and *get rid* of power and factorial. Please notice:

1. The very first term is just `x * x`
2. If you know term `item == x ** (2 * n) / (2 * n - 1)!` the next one will be `item * x * x / (2 * n) / (2 * n + 1)`.

Implementation:

```
private static double sum(double x, int count) {
  double item = x * x; // First item
  double result = item;

  for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
    // Next item from previous
    item = item * x * x / (2 * i) / (2 * i +1);       

    result += item;   
  }

  return result;
}
```

In the real world, you can notice that

```
sinh(x) = x/1! + x**3/3! + x**5/5! + ... + x**(2*n - 1) / (2*n - 1)! + ...
```

and your serie is nothing but

```
x * sinh(x) = x**2/1! + x**4 / 3! + ... + x**(2*n) / (2*n - 1)! + ...
```

So you can implement

```
private static double sum(double x) {
  return x * (Math.exp(x) - Math.exp(-x)) / 2.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below code, it will clear all your doubts (i have modified some access specifier and created main method)

```
public class SeriesSum
    {
    int x,n;
    double sum;
    SeriesSum(int xx,int nn)
    { x=xx;
    n=nn;
    sum=0.0;
    }
    double findfact(int a)
    { return (a<2)? 1:a*findfact(a-1);
    }
    double findpower(int a, int b)
    { return (b==0)? 1:a*findpower(a,b-1);
    }
    void calculate()
    { 
    System.out.println("x ="+x);    
    System.out.println("n ="+n);    
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i+=2){

        System.out.println(x+"^"+i+"/"+(i-1)+"!" +" = " +(findpower(x,i)+"/"+findfact(i-1)) );
        //System.out.println(findpower(x,i)+"/"+findfact(i-1));

        sum += findpower(x,i)/findfact(i-1);
    }
    }
    void display()
    { System.out.println("sum="+ sum);
    }
    public static void main(String arg[])
    { SeriesSum obj = new SeriesSum(3,8);
    obj.calculate();
    obj.display();
    }
}


// -----  output ----
    x =3
    n =8
    3^2/1! = 9.0/1.0
    3^4/3! = 81.0/6.0
    3^6/5! = 729.0/120.0
    3^8/7! = 6561.0/5040.0
    sum=29.876785714285713
```

Comment: OK I will do so.